# Removing characters from strings with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to brush up on my LINQ by writing some simple extension methods. Is there any better way to write such a function as below that removes a given list of characters from a string (using LINQ)?

It helps me to think of the extension methods that LINQ relies on first:

```
public static string Remove(this string s, IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    string removeChars = string.Concat(chars);

    return new string(s.ToCharArray().Where(c => !removeChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}
```

But that's pretty ugly. Ergo LINQ.

**The difference that I notice in the LINQ statement is that I have to use 'select' whereas with the extension method, I don't have to.**

```
/// <summary>Strip characters out of a string.</summary>
/// <param name="chars">The characters to remove.</param>
public static string Remove(this string s, IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    string removeChars = string.Concat(chars);

    var stripped = from c in s.ToCharArray()
                   where !removeChars.Contains(c)
                   select c;

    return new string(stripped.ToArray());
}
```

So I'm wondering if this (last snippet above) is the tersest LINQ statement to accomplish removal of characters.

Comment: I can't get either of those to work under test. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but testing both, on the string "albacore" and the chars a,b,c I would expect "lore", but I get "lbco".

Comment: @Chris Missal: It's strange, I have expected results in both cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would prefer the first form with extension methods though simplified to

```
public static string Remove(this string s, IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    return new string(s.Where(c => !chars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}
```

As for **select** keyword, it's obligatory in second form. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) says what "A query expression must terminate with either a select clause or a group clause". That's why I would avoid LINQ syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

try this for terseness

```
public static string Remove(this string source, IEnumerable<char> chars) {
  return new String(source.Where(x => !chars.Contains(x)).ToArray());
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated to correct it removing duplicates from source

Comment: Unfortunately this will remove all duplicates from source even if they are not in chars. For example, if source == "abcabc" and chars == "a" only "bc" will be returned instead of "bcbc".

Comment: @Alexander, Thanks for pointing that out.  I forgot Except had that behavior

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tend to use the first syntax for non relational situations.  When I need to perform relational operations (join), say with Expression Trees against SQL i use the later.  But, this is only because its more readable for me having used SQL for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You get a little performance increase when using a stringBuilder instead of the new string. Below results in:

StringBuilder 00:00:13.9930633 
new String 00:00:15.1495309

```
        string s = "ababababajjjaazsiajjsoajiojsioajlmmzaaokpdahgffaiojsia";
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var toRemove = new char[] { 'j', 'a', 'z' };
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length, s.Length);
            foreach (var c in s) if (!toRemove.Contains(c)) sb.Append(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder " + sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            new string(s.Where(c => !toRemove.Contains(c)).ToArray());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("new String " + sw.Elapsed);
```