# How can I get the current user-GUID in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, guid

How can I get the GUID of the current user in SharePoint 2010 with C#? The following is my code:

```
    public string readAndEncodeGUID()
    {
        Guid userGuid = Guid.Empty;

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {                
            SPWeb readWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPUser currUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            userGuid = new Guid(currUser.RawSid);
        });

        //Variable = encode USER-GUID
        return userGuid.ToString();
    }
```

The RawSid get not the right "number".

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_members.aspx) members.
You should use either the `ID` property or the `Sid` depending on what you want.
`RawSid` is the system ID of the user in binary format.

Comment: Sorry but I have tested the ID and the SID, too. It is not possible to save this IDs in the GUID-format -> Guid userGuid = new Guid(currUser.???);

Comment: Because I like the GUID format :-) How can I get the UserGUID?

Comment: Use the SPUser.ID property and convert it to GUID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825907/convert-int-to-guid

Comment: SID will never fit into a GUID format.  It's constructed based on domain authority and user type.  It just looks similar.  For storing unique key of a user, you could go with ID but that's only identifiable in SP operations. For security work outside of it, you may want to hold on to the SID.

Comment: I have thought about it. The GUID-format isn´t so important, but I need an unique number to identify the users. I thought the GUID is the best solution. Now I test other formats, too. If I use ID, I get only one number (in my opinion not so good). The SID get a good number. It is important for me that user will be exactly identified. Have you an tip for me - is SID OK for this ambition?