# Redirecting home page to altogether new page after first login

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a web application. So whenever a new user logins to the application, they will land on the home page(home.aspx), after that whenever they login to that particular web application, they will be redirected to some other page(Test.aspx). So every subsequent login, the user lands on the Test.aspx.

Please suggest any way to achieve this. I will be implementing it in Sharepoint 2010 master page.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Give the user a cookie that says he has logged in previously, and then when the document loads, check that cookie and redirect accordingly.

Comment: what if user deletes the cookie. he will again come to home page. I dont need that.

Comment: Personally, I like to assume that my users don't mess with my cookies unless they want to screw up their browsing experience slightly, as would be the case here. It would only screw it up for the next time they log in, but if you must be absolutely certain that they never come to this page again, do what Rick said. When they login, check a database, and return whether it is their first time logging in or not, and depending on that response you should redirect the user. This is harder to implement, but much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Store the landing page as a field in your db store.  Return it with your login response, and redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: can you please share any relevant link to implement this.

Comment: Here is a quick [how to](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a5f59f/how-to-create-log-in-form-in-visual-studio-and-connection-wi/) I found using Google.  This will show you how to create a login page that uses an SQL table to store the credentials.  Fom here, you would just need to add another column (depending on your needs).   You could use a bit field if it is as simple as "Never logged in go to page 1 logged in before go to page 2".  However you could also use a varchar field to store the actual URL if there is a chance you will need more than one landing page in the future.

Comment: Thinking this through some more, you are likely using Sharepoint security to log in, so you are using a Domain to log in probably... I do something similar, and I have a table that stores user based data using the [GUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099550/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-guid-in-sharepoint-2010) provided by the DC.   Do you have an SQL server available?