# Removing text between 2 strings

Tags: c#, string

I tried to write a function in C# which removes the string between two strings. Like this:

```
string RemoveBetween(string sourceString, string startTag, string endTag)
```

At first I thought this is easy, but after some time I encountered more and more problems

So this is the easy case (All examples with startTag="Start" and endTag="End")

```
"Any Text Start remove this End between" => "Any Text StartEnd between"
```

But it should also be able to handle multiples without deleting the text between:

```
"Any Text Start remove this End between should be still there Start and remove this End multiple" => "Any Text StartEnd between should be still there StartEnd multiple"
```

It should always take the smallest string to remove:

```
"So Start followed by Start only remove this End other stuff" => "So Start followed by StartEnd other stuff"
```

It should also respect the order of the the Tags:

```
"the End before Start. Start before End is correct" => "the End before Start. StartEnd is correct"
```

I tried a RegEx which did not work (It could not handle multiples):

```
public string RemoveBetween(string sourceString, string startTag, string endTag)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}(.*){1}", Regex.Escape(startTag), Regex.Escape(endTag)));
    return regex.Replace(sourceString, string.Empty);
}
```

And than I tried to work with IndexOf and Substring, but I do not see an end. And even if it would work, this cant be the most elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a approach with `string.Remove()`

```
string input = "So Start followed by Start only remove this End other stuff";
int start = input.LastIndexOf("Start") + "Start".Length;
int end = input.IndexOf("End", start);
string result = input.Remove(start, end - start);
```

I use `LastIndexOf()` because there can be multiple starts and you want to have the last one.

Comment: But this only works if "Start" and "End" is in the string one time. If there are in multiple (see example 2) it does not work. Building a loop isnt trivial too, because "Start" and "End" will stay in the string.

Comment: right, search for `LastIndexOf("Start ")` with space and loop

Answer (score 5):

You must sligthly modify your function to do a non-greedy match with `?` and `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` to work with all your examples :

```
    public static string RemoveBetween(string sourceString, string startTag, string endTag)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", Regex.Escape(startTag), Regex.Escape(endTag)), RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
        return regex.Replace(sourceString, startTag+endTag);
    }
```

Comment: This works fine with the first 2 examples, but does not work with the last.

Comment: Adding `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` would handle this last case (while still working with the 2 others examples). But  I'm not sure it covers all desired cases. (won't work with `"So Start followed by End only remove this End other stuff"`, for ex.)

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` for `.` to also match newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public static string Remove(string original, string firstTag, string secondTag)
{
   string pattern = firstTag + "(.*?)" + secondTag;
   Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

   foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(original))
   {
      original = original.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, string.Empty);
   }

   return original;
}
```

Comment: This works fine with the first 2 examples, but does not work with the last. Can you give a litte explanation what exactly the code does?

Comment: Yes, you're right. This code searches for all matches in the original string and removes them but in the 3th example is failing. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: @Gener4tor it's fixed now :)

Comment: Im sorry to say that in the text: "the End before Start. Start before End is correct" (Ill add it to the above examples) your code does some strange things.

Comment: the tag itself is not removed. is this with purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try to use LINQ like showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449513/removing-characters-from-strings-with-linq)

```
public static string Remove(this string s, IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    return new string(s.Where(c => !chars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string data = "text start this is my text end text";
            string startTag = "start";
            string endTag = "end";
            int startIndex = data.IndexOf(startTag)+ startTag.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(data.Substring(startIndex, data.IndexOf(endTag)-startIndex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in Regex Pattern Match for replacing/Getting text between two words or sentences, Original string contains  multiple line text, white spaces, tab space and special symbols in C#

```
    string startSentence = Regex.Escape( "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"redirectUrl\"" );
    string endWord = Regex.Escape( "</script>" );
    string pattern = $@"{ startSentence }[\s\S]*?{ endWord }";
    Match stringMatch = Regex.Match( PageResult, pattern );
    if( stringMatch.Success ){
    OriginalString = OriginalString.Replace( stringMatch.Value, String.Empty );
    }
```

--Regex. Escape will escape special symbols and spaces.
--Pattern which will match the text with the start sentence or word and end word,In between any more white spaces or Multiple lines or any text will ignore.
--If the substring found then MatchString has success, then move inside if and Replace, otherwise skip block
--MatchString.Value has a substring for replacing