# C# String Remove characters between two characters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string

For Example i have string Like

```
"//RemoveFromhere
 <div>
 <p>my name is blawal i want to remove this div </p>
  </div>
//RemoveTohere"
```

I want to use `//RemoveFromhere`  as starting point from where
and `//RemoveTohere` as ending point in between all character i want to remove

Comment: What do you have so far? Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use indexOf, RegEx.Split ...

Comment: Maybe this does answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891661/removing-text-between-2-strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove HTML tags from string including &nbsp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    string pattern = @"\n{0,1}//RemoveFromhere(.|\n)*?//RemoveTohere\n{0,1}";
    var result = Regex.Replace(sample, pattern, "");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static string sample = @"Here
//RemoveFromhere
 <div>
 <p>my name is blawal i want to remove this div </p>
  </div>
//RemoveTohere
Keep this.
//RemoveFromhere
 <div>
 <p>my name is blawal i want to remove this div </p>
  </div>
//RemoveTohere
Keep this too.
";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var sin = "BEFORE//RemoveFromhere"+
    "<div>"+
    "<p>my name is blawal i want to remove this div </p>"+
    "</div>"+
    "//RemoveTohereAFTER";
  const string fromId = "//RemoveFromhere";
  const string toId = "//RemoveTohere";
  var from = sin.IndexOf(fromId) + fromId.Length;
  var to = sin.IndexOf(toId);
  if (from > -1 && to > from)
    Console.WriteLine(sin.Remove(from , to - from));
//OR to exclude the from/to tags
  from = sin.IndexOf(fromId);
  to = sin.IndexOf(toId) + toId.Length;
  Console.WriteLine(sin.Remove(from , to - from));
```

This gives results `BEFORE//RemoveFromhere//RemoveTohereAFTER` and `BEFOREAFTER`

See also a more general (better) option using [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132103/1848953) from Cetin Basoz added after this answer was accepted.

Comment: What if he had more text and maybe another //Remove...//Remove... ?

Comment: I have only on place where i have "RemoveFromhere" and "RemoveTohere"

Comment: @blawalsarfraz, it is not a good idea to code for only one instance of it. But anyway it is your code.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Nice(r) answer, referenced and upvoted.